# Lines are getting deleted from file when I replace string using Python

Tags: python

I have a backup config file and an original config file.
These file contain a bunch of lines of information that are the same.

The only difference is that each config contains a "booth" and "window" number on 1 line that is different.

So the original file may have a line like

```
<file boothNumber="-1" window="-1" area="" section="">
```

The backup file may have a line like

```
<file boothNumber="325" window="3" area="" section="">
```

My program replaces the -1 in the original file with the numbers listed in the backup file.

My program scans through a list of computer or server names.
This is the start() function.

It will grab a name and run the next function which is booth().

This grabs the booth number from the backup config and saves it to the original config.

Then the window() function runs.

This grabs the window number from the backup config and saves it to the original config.

This works fine.

**PROBLEM**

I am having an issue if my original config file contains a booth and window number that is larger than the backup config file.  Once the last window() function is run, **about 10-11 lines are chopped off the end of the original config file**.

So the original file may start out like

```
<file boothNumber="4444" window="4444" area="" section="">
```

The backup file may contain

```
<file boothNumber="325" window="3" area="" section="">
```

The first booth() function will edit the original config properly.
When it gets to the second window() function, the number is edited properly **but other lines are chopped off the end of the original config file**.

What may be causing this?

If I switch the order of the booth() and window() functions, its always the second function that causes the problem.

Here is my code (It currently runs from bottom to top):

Comment: In your regex pattern you are not closing the `"` so the `re.sub` will replace everything until it will find a new `"`. You should try: `re.compile('window="[^"]+"')`. Same goes for the `booth` regex.

Comment: I would do a quick and dirty check of your regular expressions. On each iteration of both your file read loops, print "%s -> %s" (line, result..) to make sure your regular expressions are doing what you are expecting them to do. Also look for variations or mistakes that you didn't account for in the data. not very elegant, but quick

Comment: If I change them to re.compile('window="[^"]+"'), the entire config file is erased.  **EDIT** hold on, I'm double-checking because it's doing something weird

Comment: I closed my files off before jumping to next function and indented properly.  I think the combination of all this stuff fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should unindent both the:

```
window(servername) # when done, call 'window' function
```

and

```
workstationid(servername) # when done, call 'workstationID' function
```

one level.

You haven't closed off the file before you re-open it in the second function.
(ie. you're still within the `with` clause).

You really should refactor these functions as they are more or less identical (your code is not very [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)), but that is unrelated to your issue.

Comment: Thank you.  All of this and adding the " helped.